# Connecting to Heroku Postgres database with PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku

I've got an app with Heroku that I'm trying to connect to in PHP, but I'm not having any luck with.  I'm able to connect to the database in pgAdmin III, so I know I've got the right info, but PHP isn't returning anything useful to me, only false.  Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong, or even a way to get PHP to tell me something more substantial so I can troubleshoot better?

Here's my connection string:

```
$conn = pg_connect("host=ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com port=xxxx dbname=namestring user=username password=pass sslmode=require");
```

I've tried it with sslmode and without, I've tried changing the order of the parameters in the string, I just get false back when I do var_dump($conn).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are running this locally, so check that `display_errors` is enabled in your local `php.ini` and that `error_reporting` is set to something reasonable. That would be the reason you're not getting error output.

You should then see that either the connection is refused for some reason (could be your network), or that e.g. your local PHP doesn't have OpenSSL enabled (globally or for Postgres).

If this is happening on Heroku, then you'll never see errors in the page because it's a production env where `display_errors` should never be on; run `heroku logs` to see what PHP says. In this case the only reason would be that your credentials are incorrect, so check them for typos.

Which brings me to some important advice: do not hard-code these credentials (or any other config) in your code. Heroku gives you a `DATABASE_URL` env var with the connection string; read from that dynamically by using what `parse_url(getenv('DATABASE_URL'))` gives you. The reason is that your credentials may change in case Heroku needs to do an automatic failover of your database, and if you hard-code these credentials, your app would go down in this case.

If this is on Heroku, you really should run this stuff locally properly, that means with a local Postgres database as well, instead of connecting remotely to production databases, or even blindly pushing up your code to Heroku all the time without trying it locally. Much easier and faster over time.